# Multi-threading for overload and thread name is empty

Tags: c#, multithreading

This situation might seem strange but this is what i have to do:

Situation, i have a sharepoint portal and there was such an issue that there might be a problem while retrieving user profiles that there might be too slow when a lot of people online and perfrom that kind of action, so there was made a descision to make a console application to test it out.

The console application needs to simulate behavior for retrieving the user profiles with as if many different users are doing that.

And there must be a log written.

The first question is this kind of testing a good way to really know where exactly the problme is?

And the other question is about my application, i have a strange behavior:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\logfile.txt";
            string siteUrl = @"http://siteurl";
            int threads = 1;

            //Multiplicator multiplicator = new Multiplicator(filePath, siteUrl, threads);
            //Console.ReadLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(Execute);
                t.Start();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Main thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread.
          }

        static void Execute()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                using (SPSite ospSite = new SPSite(@"http://siteurl"))
                {
                    SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(ospSite);
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                    UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile("User Name");
                    string message = "Retrieved: " + userProfile.DisplayName + " on " +DateTime.Now + "by " Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So the problem is i never get the name of the thread written why?
Thread.CurrentThread.Name is empty, is it normal, maybe i initialize the threading wrong? Altho many sources said that it is done like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will go for your first question. No, there is a better way to do this.

1. Put the site under load. Maybe a friend can hit F5 all the time or you run a batch file with 1000 lines of a curl get
2. Attach the Visual Studio debugger to the webserver process
3. Hit break 10 times and see where it stops most of the time. That is your hotspot/problem.

This is called the poor mans profiler. It is built into every Visual Studio ;-)

In general, it is easy to find such problems by doing profiling. There are even sophisticated tools for this.

Comment: Could you give a link to profile sharepoint portal, and how it exactly works to find the weak zones of the sharepoint website?

Comment: There is no "link" because there is no further information on this technique. It is as simple as it sounds. What do you want to know more about?

Answer (score 3):

You have not set the name of the thread. You should do so before you start it, and you can incorporate the iteration number in the name, if you like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(Execute);
t.Name = "My Thread" + i.ToString();
t.Start();
```

They are not given names automatically. The name can only be set once, after which you would get an `InvalidOperationException`

[MSDN Reference: Thread.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx)

Incidentally, creating 100 threads is probably not a good idea under normal circumstances.

Comment: Also, `Thread.Name` does not *have* to be set only before you start the thread. That just makes sense in your case, to assure that the value is set before you would ever try to read it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it a name.   Just when you create the thread,  just name it based on i

```
Thread t = new Thread(Execute) { Name = i.ToString() };
```